# Radiobutton está solto no form

Tags: visual-basic-6

Peguei um projeto e na tela tem 3 radiobuttons. Precisei adicionar um quarto. Fui na paleta de componentes e dei dois clicks. Fazendo as devidas alteração, como caption, posição rodei o programa e quando eu clico em um dos três que já estavam, ele desmarca o que está marcado, mas quando eu clico nesse novo, ele não desmarca ninguém e ninguém desmarca ele, como se ele estivesse solto no form. Como eu faço isso? Fui copiar um já existente, me diz que já existe um componente com aquele nome. Renomeio e dá erro que já existe uma procedure com o mesmo nome, enfim, não conheço VB. Fico perdido sem saber o que fazer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Radio buttons operam dentro de um container

Cada conjunto de option/radio buttom tem que estar em um frame ou um container como um painel, por exemplo para trabalharem em conjunto. Quando você coloca ele no form, o form é o container e como os outros devem estar dentro de um painel ou grupo, eles vão operar de forma independente.

Recorte o novo radio do form e cole dentro do container dos outros radios.

Comment: Fiz isso e funcionou.

Comment: Pagotti, você já trabalhou na New Space?

Comment: @pnet Não trabalhei, deve ser algum "primo" ;)